# Does my motherboard support booting from SD card?

Tags: boot, motherboard, sd-card

How do I check if my motherboard supports booting from an SD card?

(In my case this is a Dell XPS 15 I bought sometime in 2010.)

Comment: Enter the BIOS and change the boot order of your devices.  If you can select the card reader then you can boot to it.

Answer (score 1):

Google the model number of the motherboard or the laptop and look for the manual.

Alternatively, get an SD card, put it in the reader slot and reboot the machine. Enter BIOS setup and see if you can add the sd card to the boot order.

Comment: The SD card does not show up in the boot order list. There is a generic entry "Removable Devices" but it does not list any device under it.

Comment: Make sure the card has a valid operating system on it and try again." Removable devices" might just mean USB devices. You could try a USB card reader.

Comment: @AgnelKurian - If it does not show up then you cannot boot to it.