# Trying to dual boot Linux using an SD card

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, sd-card, dualboot

**Context:**
I am trying to dual boot with windows and linux on my Laptop. My laptop has a built in sd card reader, however there are no options or methods through bios or other services that would allow me to directly boot into the sd card. However, through some testing I found that while Windows 11 and the boot menu doesn't recognize that there is an sd card reader, linux on the other hand does.

**My Goal:**
I want to use the bare minimum storage that would allow me to boot up to linux on my internal hard drive, and have the SD card contain everything else. (software, users, system files, repositories, etc.)

**Questions:**

1. How big of a partition would I need to make on my internal hard drive? ( < 32 GB)
2. Where should I set up my directories between the internal hard drive and the SD card?
3. Do I need to set up multiple partitions on my SD card for the other directories during linux installation? If yes, how much space for each directory?

Comment: If your BIOS doesn't have drivers for the card reader, you will not be able to boot from it. You are out of luck here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does my motherboard support booting from SD card?](https://superuser.com/questions/757419/does-my-motherboard-support-booting-from-sd-card)

Comment: @mashuptwice I am not trying to boot from my SD card. I am booting from a within a partition in the main hard drive of my computer, and using the SD card to store everything. I just want to know where I can put my directories so that most if not all of the required system files is on the external SD card, while booting from the hard drive within.

Comment: Your goal is actually a feature of UEFI boot process. Your computer can and should always boot from the ESP (EFI System Partition). Regardless of where the OSes are installed the bootloaders (1st stage) are saved in said partition that already exists in the internal drive. So ALL your questions are moot. Assuming the typical installers for Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives this is easily achieved by selecting "something else" for manual partitioning then select the existent EFI (again, internal drive) as such and then create the required partitions in the SD card (...)

Comment: (...) for the current Ubuntu only one partition - root - is needed nowadays but you do you. Now, this works perfectly with multiple SSDs or HDDs. Theoretically a SD card is just a drive like any other but because it relies on an external SD card reader/writer there's a lot that can go wrong. Namely a "catch 22" situation of your Linux needing drivers to work with the reader and not being able to load the OS (if running from somewhere else then the drivers are used and the SD card reader just works but Grub may not have the ability to recognize it and proceed with the boot process).

Comment: Rather than try to boot from the built-in SD card reader, which probably has its own MMC/SD controller, you can probably successfully boot with the SD card in a USB card adapter.  Linux (and the PC BIOS) will treat the USB adapter as disk drive **/dev/sdX**, rather than a **/dev/mmc** device.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How big of a partition would I need to make on my internal hard drive? ( < 32 GB)

All you would need is to be able to contain the **/boot/** directory on the internal HDD in its own partition with an ext4 filesystem.
If you only retain one copy of a kernel version, then 100MB would suffice for  this partition for the kernel and **grub**.

Using another partition on this HDD for swap would be highly recommended, both for system performance and longevity of the SD card.
The size for swap is historically recommended to be one to two times the RAM size.

---

> 2. Where should I set up my directories between the internal hard drive and the SD card?

This question does not make sense.  You already stipulated that you want to "*boot up to linux on my internal hard drive, and have the SD card contain everything else. (software, users, system files, repositories, etc.)*"

Would "*everything else*" presumably be the root filesystem?

---

> 3. Do I need to set up multiple partitions on my SD card for the other directories during linux installation? If yes, how much space for each directory?

No, you do not need to set up multiple partitions, and would be better off keeping things simple.
There really is no "*linux installation*" as you might be used to for Debian-type distributions.
Instead you could manually construct the rootfs on SD card by simply copying the rootfs of an existing Linux system, and then cleanup pertinent files in **/etc/** (e.g. **fstab**, **hostname**) and **/home/**.  (Do not copy pseudo-filesystems that are mounted at **/sys**, **/var**, and **/proc**.)

An inactive rootfs would be the ideal source (because no pseudo-filesystems would be mounted); e.g. if the rootfs is an HDD partition, then boot the PC from a **LiveCD**, manually mount that HDD partition and the SD card, and then copy the HDD partition's files & directories to the SD card.

---

During boot the rootfs on the SD card would be specified in the kernel command line with parameters such as:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 rw
```

which assumes that your SD card has one MBR partition formatted as an ext4 filesystem.

Refer to the [kernel parameters documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) for details on these parameters.

Refer to **grub** documentation on how to edit the kernel command line for the kernel you're trying to boot.

---

Note that this booting scheme requires that your Linux kernel has the driver for the MMC/SD controller built as a statically-linked driver, i.e. it's a built-in driver.
That configuration is common for embedded Linux, but may be unlikely for an x86 distributition.
If the MMC/SD controller driver is a loadable module, then booting gets complicated (e.g. use an initramfs to make the driver available, and then **mount** and **pivot_root** to the rootfs on SD card).

---

**Addendum**

I found an old laptop that has a built-in MMC/SD card socket, as well as an old Lubuntu LiveCD.  The install menu actually actually offers the SD card (as **/dev/mmcblk0**) as an installation target device.
So I proceeded to specify the HDD (**/dev/sda**) as the boot device for installation of **grub**, a primary partition (**/dev/sda1**) formatted as ext4 for mounting **/boot**, and another primary partition (**/dev/sda2**) for swap.  A single primary partition (**/dev/mmcblk0p1**) on the SD card was formatted as ext4 for mounting **/** (aka root).

The installation created all the expected directories and stored the expected files in all the expected places on the HDD and SD card.  However the boot from HDD stalls, presumably because the kernel cannot access the rootfs on the SD card due to the inaccessible module, **mmc_block.ko**.
The simplest (IMO) solution would be to rebuild a Linux kernel with the MMC/SD controller driver built-in.